# How can I reinitialize a large table?

Tags: postgresql

I use a POSTGRESQL database. I have a big problem with a table that alone is 227 GB. The table only contains 420,000 records. I did a VACUUM FULL on the table. I waited for two days but nothing. I had to stop . Same for REINDEX and TRUNCATE. I therefore looked in the directory of the DB for the files corresponding to this table. There are 227 files of 1GB each. Is there a way to reset my table?

Comment: `TRUNCATE` really should be fast.

Comment: If TRUNCATE is not finishing quickly, it is probably blocked waiting for a lock.  Figure out who is holding the lock and make them go away.